# How do I declare a function that has a parameter of a type that's defined below the declaration?

Tags: c++, function, class

I'm trying to implement custom Vector2 (2D vector) and Matrix2 (2x2 matrix) classes. I want to define a function that performs an affine transformation to a vector as if it were a point in 2D space. To do this I would need to pass the transformation matrix, an optional transformation origin and an optional translation.

I would like this function to be a member of my Vector2 class. However, my definition for Matrix2 is located underneath the definition of Vector2 that this function is defined in. As a result, when I try to compile the code I get a compile error:

> C2061 syntax error: identifier 'Matrix2'

My Matrix2 definition includes a function to multiply a matrix by a vector, so I need to define Matrix2 after Vector2.

Here is the code, with irrelevant members omitted:

```
#pragma once

namespace AWUtils
{
    struct Vector2
    {
        double x;
        double y;

        // default constructor, produces the zero vector
        Vector2()
        {
            zero();
        }

        // copy constructor, copies the given vector
        Vector2(const Vector2* v)
        {
            x = v->x;
            y = v->y;
        }

        // turns this vector into the zero vector
        void zero()
        {
            x = 0;
            y = 0;
        }

        // returns a new vector equal to this vector plus the given vector
        Vector2 add(Vector2 v)
        {
            return Vector2(x + v.x, y + v.y);
        }

        Vector2 operator + (Vector2 v)
        {
            return add(v);
        }

        Vector2 operator - (Vector2 v)
        {
            return add(v * -1);
        }

        // affine transformation
        Vector2 transform(Matrix2 matrix, Vector2 origin = Vector2(), Vector2 translation = Vector2())
        {
            Vector2 me(this);
            return (matrix * (me + translation - origin)) + origin;
        }
    };

    struct Matrix2
    {
        double a;
        double b;
        double c;
        double d;

        // vector multiplication
        Vector2 multiply(Vector2 v)
        {
            return Vector2(a * v.x + b * v.y, c * v.x + d * v.y);
        }

        Vector2 operator * (Vector2 v)
        {
            return multiply(v);
        }
    };
}
```

Do I have to just define this function elsewhere? I thought about maybe defining it under Matrix2 but I'd prefer it to be a member function. Any help (including code criticism, I've been doing C++ for just under two weeks) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looks like the culprit is `Vector2::transform`.  I would move this out of `Vector2` as a free standing function.  You may be able to wedge the function into `Matrix2`, but I don't recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

When you have two interdependent classes, as you have, you will need to forward declare one of the classes and move the implementations of member functions so that the class definitions are complete before the function implementations.

```
namespace AWUtils
{
    // Forward declaration.
    struct Matrix2;

    struct Vector2
    {
        ... 

        // Declare 
        // affine transformation
        Vector2 transform(Matrix2 matrix, Vector2 origin = Vector2(), Vector2 translation = Vector2());
    };

    struct Matrix2
    {
       ...
    };

    // Define 
    // affine transformation
    Vector2 Vector2::transform(Matrix2 matrix, Vector2 origin, Vector2 translation)
    {
        Vector2 me(this);
        return (matrix * (me + translation - origin)) + origin;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The definition should be separated from the declaration and `struct Matrix2` must be declared before `Vector2`.

```
struct Matrix2;
```

In the `Vector2`

```
Vector2 transform(const Matrix2& matrix, Vector2 origin = Vector2(), Vector2 translation = Vector2());
```

After the `Vector2` and the `Matrix2`

```
Vector2 Vectors::transform(const Matrix2& matrix, Vector2 origin, Vector2 translation)
{
    Vector2 me(this);
    return (matrix * (me + translation - origin)) + origin;
}
```

Additionally the methods should be const

```
Vector2 multiply(Vector2 v) const
{
    return Vector2(a * v.x + b * v.y, c * v.x + d * v.y);
}

Vector2 operator * (Vector2 v) const
{
     return multiply(v);
}
```